# NSMutableArray creates issue for images

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, dictionary, nsmutablearray

I have an array with dictionaries in it. Each dictionary contains UIImage & String values.

But when I try to delete object using

`[arr removeObjectAtIndex:button.tag];`

then it just decreases the count but image (Object) is not deleted.
So, my Images are overlapping when try to delete.

It also creates problem when I try to add objects in the array

`[arr insertObject:dict atIndex:0];`

so, I used 
   `[_postObj.arr_images addObject:dict];` instead of **insertObject**

**Help me to solve this**

Comment: what do you mean images are overlapped when try to delete?

Comment: are you using NSMutableArray ?

Comment: @ShamasS, Image data is persists in the image view

Comment: @Misha, Yes it is NSMutableArray

Comment: @user2526811 Do you mean that the image is still showing on the screen?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You say the UIImage isn't released, but what about the dictionary that contains it? That's what you put into the array, not the image. If the dictionary is being released, then something else must be maintaining a strong reference to your image; otherwise, it's not going to be released.

Comment: If you remove an object from an array, there is no way that it still exists in memory. May be even after you removed the image object, the imagview still have a reference to it, you have to clear image view and then remove the object or vice versa,else at somepoint it will lead to crash!!!!

Comment: please share a screen shot

Comment: @trudyscousin, it creates problem when object changes its index in the array.

Comment: Stop! You cannot edit your question to present new issues you are facing.  Create a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Objects use reference counting and both `NSMutableArray` and `UIImageView` will *retain* the `UIImage` object.

This means that removing it from the array will not automatically remove it from the `UIImageView` and you must remove it from both explicitly:

```
[arr removeObjectAtIndex:button.tag];
_imageView.image = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your frame setting of `UIImageView`. Please try using below code (not tested by myself) and see if this fixes the issue for you. Basically, I am adjusting X position of images based on previous image's width.

```
CGFloat imageXM = 5.0;
CGFloat imageXPos = 0;

for (UIImage *image in arr_images) {
    CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(imageXPos + imageXM, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    imageXPos = imageXPos + image.size.width;

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];

    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    imageView.image = image;
    [scl addSubview:imageView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As in your code

```
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [arr_images insertObject:chosenImage atIndex:0];
        [self scrollImages_Setup2];

    }];
```

[arr_images insertObject:chosenImage atIndex:0]; that means you need only one image to display on scroll view. Then why you take a loop:

```
-(void)scrollImages_Setup2
{    
    for (int k=0; k<arr_images.count; k++) {

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((CGRectGetWidth(scl.frame) * k) + CGRectGetWidth(scl.frame), 0, CGRectGetWidth(scl.frame), CGRectGetHeight(scl.frame))];

        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        imageView.image=[arr_images objectAtIndex:k] ;
        [scl addSubview:imageView];
    }

    scl.contentSize = CGSizeMake((CGRectGetWidth(scl.frame) * arr_images.count)+CGRectGetWidth(scl.frame), CGRectGetHeight(scl.frame));

}
```

You just right the code only for display the Image. you don't need to scroll view for displaying only one image. I think you are not clear what you want.

Your problem regarding the overwriting the images because of loop. so remove the loop, when you display a single image. Please remove the scrollview contentSize, because image_array will increase, when you add the multiple images in array and size width will be large. so remove arr_images.count as well.

Comment: thanks for your reply.
plz understand the code before posting an answer.
` [arr_images insertObject:chosenImage atIndex:0];` does not mean array has only one value

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but In the code you always replace the value at index: 0 , that means you want to replace the first image of array, and you newer mentioned anywhere that you have a list of images, that is the reason I assumed. Next time I will assume more deeply. Thanks